# Using Single ByteArrayOut/InputStream and ObjectOut/Input for Multiple Operations

Tags: java, serialization

I have written a basic server-client architecture in Java and I am using serializable classes for packet transmission. I have probably seen the "tobytearray, frombytearray" functions in some question on stackoverflow. The server works and must work real-time so there are nearly more than 20-30 packets sent in a second. And when i read a packet, or write a packet, I serialize the class and this operation might cost badly because I constantly create a new ObjectOutputStream and a ByteArrayOutputStream with it, when you think it happens 30 times in a second it is probably chopping the performance. So i thinking of creating a static ByteArrayOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream in the main class, so every Packet uses them while serializing or deserializing themselves, which are already created so i will escape from the price of allocating something 30 times in a second. But will it cause another performance hit ? And should i flush or reset the ByteArrayStream each time ?

Answer (score 1):

> when you think it happens 30 times in a second it is probably chopping the performance

Really? Computers are pretty fast, you know. Unless these are really *enormous* byte arrays, I very very much doubt that it's a problem.

As ever:

- Define performance criteria before you start coding
- Write the simplest code you can to achieve your goal correctly
- Test the performance against the criteria you specified
- *If* the performance is unsatisfactory, profile your application to work out where the largest bottlenecks are
- Address the bottlenecks, losing simplicity only where the performance benefits prove significant
- Repeat until your code meets the performance criteria

My guess is that you haven't started testing performance yet. You'd be amazed at how much work a computer can do 30 times in a second.